# IntelliJ is generating private getters

Tags: java, intellij-idea

My IntelliJ has been generating private getters for a few weeks now, which is weird because it does not respect the default template:

```
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
  static ##
#end
$field.type ##
#set($name = $StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project))))
#if ($field.boolean && $field.primitive)
  #if ($StringUtil.startsWithIgnoreCase($name, 'is'))
    #set($name = $StringUtil.decapitalize($name))
  #else
    is##
#end
#else
  get##
#end
${name}() {
  return $field.name;
}
```

I've been searching for a while what could cause this but no result. Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Which version of Idea? Are you create getter via Refactoring submenu, or via Alt+Insert - Getter?

Comment: IDEA CE 15.0.1. I'm using Alt+Insert.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My guess is your *Default Visibility* setting in *File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | Java* is set to Private.